# What is the mechanism of the reaction between 1(3H)-Isobenzofuranone and benzaldehyde?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

I have been trying to deduce a reaction mechanism for the reaction between the two compounds to give the compound labeled 2 in the diagram but I do not think I have a satisfactory answer. My thinking is that a strong base deprotonates the carbon adjacent to the oxygen in the cyclic system which then attacks the carbonyl of the benzaldehyde in an aldol type reaction to give the final product.
Is this a correct mechanism and if not, which is? I have tried looking for the reaction conditions and reagents but Wikimedia does not cite any references.
[image]

Comment: Redraw the double bonds in the benzene ring and you will find that the reaction site is an active methylene and can attack the aldehyde in a straightforward vinylogous aldol reaction. It could probably go under acid catalysis e.g. Toluene/PTSA Dean-Stark reflux. See more here: pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cr990247i

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but that looks like most obvious step in this reaction.